# Get-AzureRmApplicationInsightsApiKey cmd is returning a null primary key

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, azure-application-insights

I am currently working with AZURE Resources. The Goal is to generate a specific resource API KEY and accessing that key from powershell.

I first ran,

```
New-AzureRmApplicationInsightsApiKey -ResourceId {RID}
```

to generate the API Key for my resource. I manually checked the Azure Portal and the key was indeed generated.

I next ran the following command in order to get this API Key from powershell.

```
Get-AzureRmApplicationInsightsApiKey -ResourceId {RID}
```

I got the result I wanted (shown below) but the API KEY is showing null or blank.

```
ApiKey      : 

CreatedDate : Wed, 22 May 2019 23:36:40 GMT

Id          : 7c4c61dc-b392-4aa4-992f-ee92b84e5dee

Permissions : {ReadTelemetry}

Description : test1
```

I can access the API Key and its information but I am not seeing anything defined for the actual key, it is showing blank. The Microsoft Docs seem to show this same result but I have not found a way to show the key value.

I need to figure out how to uncover and access this key value. I want to store this key in an object for access.

I am getting a null value for the key when I do the following.

```
$apikeyinfo= Get-AzApplicationInsightsApiKey -ResourceId {RID} 

$apikey = $apikeyinfo.ApiKey
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it appears to be blank in the sample results as well so its likely obfuscated from the display.  Have you tried passing or using the key object?  You clearly have a valid key, what is the error you are trying to get past?

Comment: Yes I have tried to store the key object. I can access the Id, Permissions, and even the key itself of the object. The key will just display null here in this case as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue. It seems you can't get the key after create it. If you create the key in the portal, you will find that as below. Azure will not store the key, after you close this blade you won't be able to see it again.

[image]

Also, it was mentioned in the [official doc](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization/API-key-and-App-ID).

[image]

So your workaround is to store the apikey when it was created, e.g. `Out-File`

```
$apikey = New-AzureRmApplicationInsightsApiKey -ResourceGroupName "joywebapp" -Name "joyinsight" -Description "testapiKey1" -Permissions @("ReadTelemetry", "WriteAnnotations")
$apikey.ApiKey | Out-File "C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\apikey.txt"
```

Or you can store the object directly, then import it when you need to use it again.

```
$apikey = New-AzureRmApplicationInsightsApiKey -ResourceGroupName "joywebapp" -Name "joyinsight" -Description "testapiKey2" -Permissions @("ReadTelemetry", "WriteAnnotations")
$apikey | Export-Csv "C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\apikey1.csv"

$key = Import-Csv "C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\apikey1.csv"
$key.ApiKey
```

**Besides**, if you want to store the key in local, I recommend you to store it in the azure keyvault, then you can retrive the key in the keyvault, more details see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/quick-create-powershell).

Comment: Right, manually creating the key will only show me the key one time. 

In my case, I am generating the key from powershell. I want to then access that key that has been generated as I want to proceed with running another command that will need use of that key.

Comment: @DiegoCohen In short, you cannot get the key value after you create it. I think my solution is useful enough, you can try it.

Comment: Yes this worked. I can save it in an external file but I rather use the Key Vault for security reasons. Thanks!